# print first 3 characters and / rest of the string with stars

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'have this input like this

```
John:boofoo
```

I want to print rest of the string with stars and keep only 3 characters of the string.

The output will be like this

```
John:boo***
```

this my command

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1,$2 ":***"}'
```

I want to use only print command if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following. This will print stars(keeping only first 3 letters same as it is) how many characters are present in 2nd field after first 3 characters.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=":"
}
{
  stars=""
  val=substr($2,1,3)
  for(i=4;i<=length($2);i++){
    stars=stars"*"
  }
  $2=val stars
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
John:boo***
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                          ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=":"                    ##Setting FS and OFS value as : here.
}                               ##Closing block of BEGIN section here.
{                               ##Here starts main block of awk program.
  stars=""                      ##Nullifying variable stars here.
  val=substr($2,1,3)            ##Creating variable val whose value is 1st 3 letters of 2nd field.
  for(i=4;i<=length($2);i++){   ##Starting a for loop from 4(becasue we need to have from 4th character to till last in 2nd field) till length of 2nd field.
    stars=stars"*"              ##Keep concatenating stars variable to its own value with *.
  }
  $2=val stars                  ##Assigning value of variable val and stars to 2nd field here.
}
1                               ##Mentioning 1 here to print edited/non-edited lines for Input_file here.
' Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Perfect good idea to identify the length of the string not just 3stars. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
echo 'John:boofoo' | sed -E 's/(:...).*/\1***/'
```

Output:

```
John:boo***
```

Comment: It is unclear whether OP wants all the remaining characters to be replaced by `*` or print three `*` whatever the number of remaining characters is.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {print $1, substr($2,1,3) gensub(/./,"*","g",substr($2,4))}' file
John:boo***
```

With any awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {tl=substr($2,4); gsub(/./,"*",tl); print $1, substr($2,1,3) tl}' file
John:boo***
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even with good old `sed`

```
$ echo "John:boofoo" | sed 's/...$/***/'
```

Output:

```
John:boo***
```

(**note**: this just replaces the last 3 characters of any string with `"***"`, so if you need to key off the `':'`, see the GNU `sed` answer from Cyrus.)

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` variant:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1 FS substr($2, 1, 3) "***"}' <<< 'John:boofoo'
```

```
John:boo***
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed : replace all chars after the third by *

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^:]*:...)(.*)[^*]([*]*)/\1\2\3*/;tA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{s=sprintf("%0*d",length(substr($2,4)),0); gsub(/0/,"*",s);print $1,substr($2,1,3) s}' infile
```

You can use the `%*` form of [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), which accepts a variable width. And, if you use '0' as your value to print, combined with the right-aligned text that's zero padded on the left..

***Better Readable:***

```
awk 'BEGIN{
       FS=OFS=":"
     }
     {
       s=sprintf("%0*d",length(substr($2,4)),0); 
       gsub(/0/,"*",s);
       print $1,substr($2,1,3) s
     }
     ' infile
```

***Test Results:***

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.

$ cat f
John:boofoo

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{s=sprintf("%0*d",length(substr($2,4)),0); gsub(/0/,"*",s);print $1,substr($2,1,3) s}' f
John:boo***
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we have the tags awk, bash and sed: for completeness sake here is a bash only solution:

```
INPUT="John:boofoo"
printf "%s:%s\n" ${INPUT%%:*} $(TMP1=${INPUT#*:};TMP2=${TMP1:3}; echo "${TMP1:0:3}${TMP2//?/*}")
```

It uses two arguments to `printf` after the format string. The first one is `INPUT` stripped of by everything uncluding and after the `:`. Lets break down the second argument `$(TMP1=${INPUT#*:};TMP2=${TMP1:3}; echo "${TMP1:0:3}${TMP2//?/*}")`:

- `$(...)` the string is interpreted as a bash command its output is substituted as last argument to `printf`

  - `TMP1=${INPUT#*:};` remove everything up to and including the `:`, store the string in `TMP1`.
  - `TMP2=${TMP1:3};` geht all characters of `TMP1` from offset 3 to the end and store them in `TMP2`.
  - `echo "${TMP1:0:3}${TMP2//?/*}"` output the temporary strings: the first three chars from `TMP1` unmodified and all chars from `TMP2` as `*`
  - the output of the last echo is the last argument to `printf`

Here is the bash -x output:

```
+ INPUT=John:boofoo
++ TMP1=boofoo
++ TMP2=foo
++ echo 'boo***'
+ printf '%s:%s\n' John 'boo***'
John:boo***
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pure Bash, using the builtin regular expression predicate.

```
input="John:boofoo"
if [[ $input =~ ^([^:]*:...)(.*)$ ]]; then
    printf '%s%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//?/*}"
else
    echo >&2 "String doesn't match pattern"
fi
```

We split the string in two parts: the first part being everything up to (and including) the three chars found after the first colon (stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`), the second part being the remaining part of string (stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`). If the string doesn't match this pattern, we just insult the user.

We then print the first part unchanged, and the second part with every character replaced with `*`.